# Firebase Cloud Messaging, in onRefreshToken, I can't access my preferences

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing Firebase Cloud Messaging under Android Sudio on Ubuntu after I have deleted my android app that implements it on my target phone.
As explained in the documentation, onRefreshToken is called when I start the app for the first time. I try to send the token to my app server, whose URL is stored in the app's Preferences.

Unfortunately I can't read the preferences until after onCreate runs, which is after the onRefreshToken runs. Thus I can't send the new token automatically to my server.

How can I get round this , preferably by being able to read the preferences in the onRefreshToken callback?

Comment: You need to read preferences from the `onTokenRefresh()` then you may call the your application server.

Comment: @NitinMisra - no I can't. I need a context to read the preference. I haven't got one until after onCreate

Comment: That's nonsense. You get a context in the onTokenRefresh

Comment: @TimCastelijns - yes I am wrong. Because I've removed the entire app, all the preferences I had changed and saved have gone too, To make my app personalisable, I will have to store the default URL etc in a file on the phone, outside the app entirely. I'll have to have a think about the best way to do that.

Comment: Seems like an overly complicated solution for the issue you mention, good luck though

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here it is, this is how you can get the context, it was so straight forward.